# GO test gives very strange error - cannot find package command-line-a/vendor

Tags: go

I've update to GO 1.6 and now I get very strange error when running `go test`

```
pawel@pawel:~/work/src/...../web/workers$ go test email_test.go 
# command-line-arguments
email_test.go:16:2: cannot find package "command-line-a/vendor/github.com/jpoehls/gophermail" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/command-line-a/vendor/github.com/jpoehls/gophermail (from $GOROOT)
    /home/pawel/work/src/command-line-a/vendor/github.com/jpoehls/gophermail (from $GOPATH)
    /home/pawel/work/src/...../web/_vendor/src/command-line-a/vendor/github.com/jpoehls/gophermail
FAIL    command-line-arguments [setup failed]
```

I've also tried to run it with `go test email_test.go email.go` but  result is the same. I grep for "command-line" in my whole project and vendor and haven't find it.

Running `go run email.go` works correctly. My project dependencies are in directory `vendor` (which is one level higher), it contains  `github.com/jpoehls/gophermail`

Comment: You test packages, not files like you build and install packages and not files.

Comment: Thanks @Volker, indeed when I test packages it works. Nevertheless it doesn't explain why I get such a strange error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @volker explained in a comment, my problem was that I wanted to test files instead of packages. 
When I reorganize my project and test simply by `go test` it works fine.

Nevertheless it doesn't explain why I get such a strange error.